# Conditionally separating variables dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Consider the minimal working example of a very messy data set I am working with:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x<- paste(sort(rep(LETTERS[1:4], 3)), paste0(rep("#", 3), rep(11:13, 3)))
y<- paste(sort(rep(LETTERS[1:4], 2)), paste0(rep(1:2, 2), rep("/0", 2)))
data<- data.frame(Item = c(x, y))
```

which gives:

```
    Item
1  A #11
2  A #12
3  A #13
4  B #11
5  B #12
6  B #13
7  C #11
8  C #12
9  C #13
10 D #11
11 D #12
12 D #13
13 A 1/0
14 A 2/0
15 B 1/0
16 B 2/0
17 C 1/0
18 C 2/0
19 D 1/0
20 D 2/0
```

I want to separate Item into Item and Size. There are two types of sizes. The first, 11:13 which are identified by `#`. The second, 1/0:2/0 which can be identified by `/0` in this example. To separate the first size type from Item `data %>% separate(Item, into = c("Item", "Size"), sep = "#")` is used. This, however, outputs `NA` in rows 13:20.

How would one separate a variable as per a condition such that the Item and Size of the second size type may be separated?

I have tried the code below without any success.

```
data %>% 
        separate(Item, into = c("Item", "Size"), sep = "#") %>% 
        mutate(ifelse(grepl("/0", Item) == TRUE, separate(Item, into = c("Item", "Size"), sep = " (?=[^ ]+$)", perl=TRUE), Size))
```

**EDIT**

The desired output should look like this:

```
   Item Size
1     A   11
2     A   12
3     A   13
4     B   11
5     B   12
6     B   13
7     C   11
8     C   12
9     C   13
10    D   11
11    D   12
12    D   13
13    A  1/0
14    A  2/0
15    B  1/0
16    B  2/0
17    C  1/0
18    C  2/0
19    D  1/0
20    D  2/0
```

Comment: What should `Size` look like for rows 13:20?

Comment: Have you tried `data %>% 
  separate(Item, into = c("Item", "Size"), sep = " ")`

Comment: Why do you need `separate`? Can't you just use `gsub` to remove the letters from Item, leaving just the appropriate numbers?

Comment: As @divibisan asks, what do you want to keep from "A 1/0"? "A" and "1"? Would running another command be okay (which is easy to do) or all in one line?

Comment: I have edited the question to provide the desired output. I understand that for this example `Item` and `Size` can be separated by the space as per @Kerry Jackson. However, in the original dataset, I am working with far messier character strings in `Item` before separation. Item descriptions are from one to five words long and the size may not always necessarily at the end of the string.  Therefore, I am wondering if variables can be separated conditionally by means of an `ifelse()` function or other functions. Running another command (or more) is fine @Sahir Moosvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Size` has pattern <`#` and digit> or digit after blank, this goes to `sep` argument.

1. `" #(?=[0-9])"` finds the pattern such as `" #1"`
2. `" [0-9]"` finds the pattern such as `" 1"`
3. `|` means *or*

In sum, (*Assuming these kinds of pattern do not occur in item name*)

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- paste(sort(rep(LETTERS[1:4], 3)), paste0(rep("#", 3), rep(11:13, 3)))
y <- paste(sort(rep(LETTERS[1:4], 2)), paste0(rep(1:2, 2), rep("/0", 2)))
mydf <- data_frame(Item = c(x, y))
#---------------------------------
mydf %>% 
  separate(Item, into = c("Item", "Size"), sep = " #(?=[0-9])| (?=[0-9])")
#> # A tibble: 20 x 2
#>    Item  Size 
#>    <chr> <chr>
#>  1 A     11   
#>  2 A     12   
#>  3 A     13   
#>  4 B     11   
#>  5 B     12   
#>  6 B     13   
#>  7 C     11   
#>  8 C     12   
#>  9 C     13   
#> 10 D     11   
#> 11 D     12   
#> 12 D     13   
#> 13 A     1/0  
#> 14 A     2/0  
#> 15 B     1/0  
#> 16 B     2/0  
#> 17 C     1/0  
#> 18 C     2/0  
#> 19 D     1/0  
#> 20 D     2/0
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question the | operator lets you select multiple separators.

```
data %>% 
  separate(Item, into = c("Item", "Size"), sep = " #| ")
```

Or you could use the common " " character to split everything and then clean up the column after:

```
data %>% 
      separate(Item, into = c("Item", "Size"), sep = " ")
```

See https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html for more regex info to help your cleaning. If it's untidy text you're gonna love and need stringR

Comment: Third option is `separate(Item, into = c("Item", "Size"), sep = " #?")`

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are looking for. Split on the space and then replace either # or /0 with blank, unless I misunderstood.

```
data %>%
  separate(Item, into = c("Item", "Size"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(Size = gsub("/0|#", "", Size))
```